# Xcode 6.4 not showing local variable while debugging

Tags: debugging, xcode6.4

When I debug my code I'm NOT getting block variables in the variables view.
It's strange but I'm not getting the reason behind it. You can check it in the screenshot. I have tried by changing the mode to "auto" or "local variable" or "All Variables".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are in Release mod.
In Xcode menu go to Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme in Run tab check "Build Configuration" is Debug.
Hope to help you.

Comment: This resolve my problem. Should be correct answer, I guess.